# Passing multiple values to Toast

Tags: java, android, radio-button, toast

I have been trying to make a small application to learn android development, I have set up 4 radio buttons each representing a different color. My problem is that I cannot find a way to pass the values from the radio buttons to the toast if the user selects them, for example if the user selects yellow and blue the toast would output that the user had selected the colors blue and yellow, I can only find documentation to pass one value to the toast.

How to over come this?

```
chooseColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        blue = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        red = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        yellow = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        green = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        brown = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        blue.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);            
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);                   
        toast.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only pass a single String to `Toast.makeText()` to be displayed in the Toast. However, you can easily build up a String with all the information that you desire by using `+` to concatenate Strings together or a `StringBuilder` to create one more dynamically.

As a side note, your current code will show "Blue" whether or not the blue radio button is selected. You will need several `if` statements to determine which radio buttons are selected.

Answer (score 0):

I just agree with Code-Guru, besides u should check if something is checked in your onClick method, it is better this way:

```
chooseColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {

        blue = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        red = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        yellow = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        green = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        brown = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);


        String str = ", ";
        str += blue.isChecked()?blue.getText()+", ":"";
        str += red.isChecked()?red.getText()+", ":"";
        str += yellow.isChecked()?yellow.getText()+", ":"";
        str += green.isChecked()?green.getText()+", ":"";
        str += brown.isChecked()?brown.getText()+", ":"";
        str = str.subString(0,str.length()-2);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);            
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);                   
        toast.show();

    }
});
```

in addition, if chooseColor is a RadioGroup which contains radiobuttons, u may not be able to check several radiobuttons(I am not sure but this gotta be way.)

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why you think "it is better this way". (Not that I disagree.)

Comment: it does not refer your solution or you, 'it' refers David's code and I guess it is better because it is working on my project.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I am simply suggesting that you an explanation to your answer. There are certainly other ways to do this that will compile and run. Why is your suggested solution better than other alternatives? Why does your suggestion improve on the OP's code?